# How do I add a user to a group in Ubuntu Server Autoinstall?

Tags: server, 22.04, docker, autoinstall

I'm trying to configure docker in my Ubuntu server autoinstaller.

Most everything has worked as expected, but I cannot figure out how to get my user to be added to docker group as a part of this autoinstall.

If I use the `identity:` fields, that works fine to create the user but then I'm unable to add the user to the docker group.

So then I tried the `users:` feature in the "user-data" file, but that causes the installer to hang and never finish:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  users:
    - name: dev
      passwd: "$y$j9T$XepKXdMTA7iJf8iCSNxpq.$0rSTu6/CrWNDM/wZvfSY0otUBUP5GjAKTvWiZ2puxS2"
      primary_group: dev
      groups: docker
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: us
  ssh:
    install-server: true

  apt:
    sources:
      docker:
        # https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/
        source: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
        # 
        key: |
          -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
          <pgp text is here but figured that didn't need to make the post longer>
          -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
  
  packages:
    - tree
    - wget
    - curl
    - gnupg
    - ca-certificates
    - lsb-release
    - docker-ce
    - docker-ce-cli
    - containerd.io
  
  late-commands:
    - cp /cdrom/data_files/setup.sh /target/root/
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod +x /root/setup.sh
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash /root/setup.sh
    - shutdown -h now
```

So I went back to the `identity:` fields, and tried other things.

As you can see with my late commands, I call a script. I have tried adding `usermod -aG docker dev` to that script, but then the script fails with error code -1. No other information that I can glean.

Additionally, I've tried adding the same usermod command in `late-commands`, which fails. I then tried adding the usermod command to `runcmd` which also fails. I can't determine what the failure is, as the logs simply say it failed or returns a 6 error code. I tried looking that up with no luck.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what that is. What is the correct way to add a user to the docker group, or any group for that matter, as part of the autoinstaller?

Edit:

Per a suggestion I tried this format for the `users:` section. While the installation finishes, I'm unable to login.

```
  user-data:
    users:
      - default
      - name: dev
        passwd: "$y$j9T$XepKXdMTA7iJf8iCSNxpq.$0rSTu6/CrWNDM/wZvfSY0otUBUP5GjAKTvWiZ2puxS2"
        primary_group: dev
        groups: users, admin, docker
        sudo: ALL=(ALL)
    hostname: FixMe
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include the 'users' section within a 'user-data' section.  Something like this:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1

  locale: en_US

  keyboard:
    layout: us

  ssh:
    install-server: true

  apt:
    sources:
      docker:
        # https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/
        source: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
        # 
        key: |
          -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
          <pgp text is here but figured that didn't need to make the post longer>
          -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
  
  packages:
    - tree
    - wget
    - curl
    - gnupg
    - ca-certificates
    - lsb-release
    - docker-ce
    - docker-ce-cli
    - containerd.io
  
  late-commands:
    - cp /cdrom/data_files/setup.sh /target/root/
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod +x /root/setup.sh
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash /root/setup.sh
    - shutdown -h now

  user-data:
    users:
      - name: dev
        passwd: "$y$j9T$XepKXdMTA7iJf8iCSNxpq.$0rSTu6/CrWNDM/wZvfSY0otUBUP5GjAKTvWiZ2puxS2"
        primary_group: dev
        groups: docker

    hostname: computername
    fqdn: copmutername.something.something
```

In my working autoinstall here is what I have listed under users:

```
    - name: localuser
      gecos: Local Ubuntu User
      sudo: ALL=(ALL) (ALL)
      passwd: <hashed password>
      shell: /bin/bash
      groups: [adm, cdrom, dip, lxd, sudo]
      lock_passwd: false
```

And I generated the password using the following:

```
mkpasswd --method=SHA-512
```

Note: You'll have to do this on a separate system.  mkpasswd is part of the whois package.

Comment: This change allowed the installation to finish, but I'm unable to login. I've been using the same username/password this whole time, but I cannot login this time around. Am I missing any parameters under `users:` that is necessary for the user to be functional?

Comment: I updated my above post with what I have for a working example.  Something you could try is just using a plain text password for testing to validate that everything else is working as expected.  To do this... replace the `passwd:` line with `plain_text_passwd: somepassword`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Now that I review... I'm willing to bet the issue is with this:

`lock_passwd: (boolean) Disable password login. Default: true`

You probably just need to add `lock_passwd: false`

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to your example, but in the time between my questions and your response, I ended up at the same options by brute force trial and error, and it still didn't work. What I came to understand is that the user is not created until after the restart. That's not explained anywhere in the docs that I have seen, but once I restarted the system, and then restarted it again, I had a working user. That has worked consistently for me. That really needs to be documented better.

Comment: @granitdev - You're right about the documentation.  You are correct in that the `auto-install` options are used to answer the installer questions and the `user-data` section is run on first boot after the initial install.  From what I can tell if you still want to power off everything at the very end you can use the `power_state` module.

For reference from my bookmarks:

[Autoinstall module reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference)
[User-Data module reference](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#)